# Is there a SIMPLE way to show my images hosted on flickr on my website and use Lightbox?

Tags: html, image, lightbox, flickr

I have a website that I put my photos on.

I host the thumbnails and the larger 1024px wide versions are hosted on Photobucket and I use a simple adapted bit of html to get the 1024 versions to show in Lightbox2 after a thumbnail is clicked on. I've also integrated a very flimsy java right click deactivation on the site.

It is www.wingsnthings.eclipse.co.uk

(I've tried and failed to include a bit of the html here that displays the images but it just tries to convert it into an image and fails.)

I want to change all of the hosting over to Flickr thanks to the space given but so far in sandbox testing am failing to get any Flickr-hosted images (using the code supplied by flickr that gives thumbnails as well) to show in my existing setup using Lightbox. Without routing through Lightbox the images do show up but seemingly still based on the Flickr site. OK, this may be seen as advantageous as people can then get to my other albums etc but I'd like to keep the current features as they are.

Is there a way to get them to show in Lightbox (or similar) and the user can then scroll through all of those that I have listed thumbnails for?

Comment: There is a post on the forum already that addresses this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859655/can-i-add-lightbox-to-flickr-feed

Comment: Thanks for your help Aaron but my title was carefully worded. I found that thread and a couple of others but their explanations were in no way what I would describe as SIMPLE, or at least there was no simple explanation with them.
That passage of JS may as well have been written in Klingon for all the sense it made I'm afraid! ;)